# Data entry form: retrieve and edit records by date

Tags: excel, vba

I found a tutorial on YouTube which sets up a simple data entry form which allows you to create, retrieve, edit and delete records contained in a table.  The data in the example is organized by Employee ID#'s which populate a drop down combobox.  However, my table will be organized by Dates. So, I want the combobox to populate with these dates and to retrieve the corresponding data depending on the date selected.

Edit:  The Table in the tutorial is organized like:   Col A Employee ID#  ... Col B Employee Name ... Col C Gender ... Col D Job Title ... Col E Salary
and there's 4 rows of entries

I've searched online and fooled around but can't seem to get it to recognize dates. The closest I've gotten is converting the dates to  serial# format (i.e. 43617 etc.) and then everything works. However, I would prefer to use a traditional mm/dd/yyyy format.

Here's the code:

This populates combobox (combobox2) with the data column that contains the employee ID#'s (which I want to replace with dates).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim n As Long

Me.ComboBox2.Clear
Me.ComboBox2.AddItem ""

For n = 3 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sh.Range("A" & n).Value
Next n

    
End Sub
```

Here's the code from ComboBox2 which populates the employee record fields (Textbox2 & 3, ComboBox1 and Option button 1 2) depending on the Employee ID# selected.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim i As Long
   
If Me.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
   If VBA.IsError(Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.ComboBox2.Value), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)) = True Then
       MsgBox "Record Not found for this EMP ID", vbCritical
       Exit Sub
   Else
       i = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.ComboBox2.Value), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
   End If
   
   Me.TextBox2.Value = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
   
   If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = "Male" Then Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
   If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = "Female" Then Me.OptionButton2.Value = True
   
   Me.ComboBox1.Value = sh.Range("D" & i).Value

   Me.TextBox3.Value = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
   
   Else
   
   Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
   Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
   
   Me.OptionButton1.Value = False
   Me.OptionButton2.Value = False
   
   Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
   
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel (and VBA) store dates and times internally as numbers - those are the numbers you see when you populate the Combobox. You can easily convert this date into a string using the `Format`-function.

```
For n = 3 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem Format(sh.Range("A" & n).Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")
Next n
```

Now your Combobox contains strings that look like a date - but be aware that they are strings! Now in your `Change`-routine, you need to convert this string back to a date. VBA offers the `CDate`-function for that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim i As Variant
   
    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim d As Date
    d = CDate(Me.ComboBox2.Value)
    i = Application.Match(CDbl(d), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
        
    If IsError(i) Then
        MsgBox "Record Not found for this EMP ID", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    (...)
End Sub
```

Turns out that `Match` doesn't work unless you explicitly convert that date into a number. I use `CDbl` for that, but as long as you have only dates (without time part), `CLng` will do also.

Be aware that depending on the *format* you choose and your regional settings, the function `CDate` may fail (eg mixing date and month). In that case, you need to split the date string into pieces and use the `DateSerial`-function. The following function assumes a format "dd.mm.yyyy", but can easily be adapted:

```
Function MyCDate(s As String) As Date
    Dim dateparts() As String
    dateparts = Split(s, ".")
    If UBound(dateparts) <> 2 Then Exit Function
    MyCDate = DateSerial(Val(dateparts(2)), Val(dateparts(1)), Val(dateparts(0)))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify these two lines to:

```
Me.ComboBox2.AddItem Format(sh.Range("A" & n).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

If VBA.IsError(Application.Match(VBA.DateValue(Me.ComboBox2.Value), sh.Range("A:A"), 0)) = True Then
```